# SMPlayer playlist works only sometimes

Tags: playlists, smplayer

I have uninstalled Ubuntu built in player and instead of it i installed SMPlayer. When i want play more songs in playlist sometimes it automatically plays song after song but mostly it stops on every song so i must play it manually. I want it to play automaticaly.
I was looking for it in settings but there was nothing about playlists. Im using latest Ubuntu 13, but i had this even in 12.04 and 12.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same issue and found this:

> This is an audio related issue. If this is happening to you, then
>   please set SMPlayer to have direct access to the sound device, rather
>   than via a daemon like esd or pulseaudio (Default for Ubuntu)
>
> So the following would work:
>
> ```
> killall pulseaudio esd
> ```
>
> SMPlayer Options->Preferences->Audio Tab Set "Output Driver" to "alsa" OK

See the [original post here](http://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?60780-smplayer-playlist-repeat-problems).